# Swift class ivars - instantiation time

Tags: swift

Lets say you have a class.

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController {

   private var _dataSource = SomeOtherClass()


   init() {
       // --> breakpoint

       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }

}
```

At the breakpoint in `init` - I can see that `_dataSource` is already allocated. At what point is the class actually getting allocated, and when do the class iVars also get init?

Are there some docs on what happens under the hood?

And what's the difference compared to this?

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController {

   private var _dataSource: SomeOtherClass!


   init() {
       _dataSource = SomeOtherClass()
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }

}
```

Thanks,

p.s. Coming from Obj-C to Swift world.

Comment: Leading underscores aren't common practice in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift, iVar's are assimilated with properties, so I'll be using the term "property" in the rest of the answer.

Property initialization code runs right before running the code of any initializer, as part of a compiler-genarated "initializer". One method to find out about this is by initializing the property from a function, and set a breakpoint inside that function:

```swift
class SomeClass: UIViewController {

    private var _dataSource = {
        // --> breakpoint
        return SomeOtherClass()
    }()


   init() {
       // --> breakpoint

       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }
}
```

You should see a stacktrace like this
[image]

BTW, in your second code snippet you don't need to declare the property as implicitly unwrapped, as long as you give it a value either inline or within the initializer the compiler will be happy.

The answer to your second question is that, at runtime, there are no differences between assigning the property the value inline (at the declaration site), or within the initializer. There are other advantages/disadvantages with both approaches, at compile time, like with multiple initializers giving a value inline avoids code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Swift does not expose allocation or bare iVars. Only init methods and properties are exposed.

Do not make assumptions about how allocation is done or how iVars are initialized. The compiler is free to optimize those details in any way it chooses.

---

Declaration of properties are straight forward.

```swift
class SomeClass: UIViewController {
     // This is an instance property. It must be set in init(…) before the call to
     // super.init(…).
    var _dataSource1: SomeOtherClass

    // This is an instance property that is set in its declaration. A way to think
    // of this is to imagine it being set after allocation and before init(…) is
    // called.
    var _dataSource2 = SomeOtherClass()

    // This is a lazy property. Instead of being set in init(…), lazy properties
    // are set when they are first used.
    lazy var _dataSource3 = SomeOtherClass()

    // This is a class property accessed with SomeClass._dataSource4. All static
    // properties are lazy. So, they are set on first use.
    static var _dataSource4 = SomeOtherClass()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization in Swift is a [two-phase process](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID220). In the first phase, each property is assigned an initial value. Whereas in Objective-C this meant assigning zeroes and null values, in Swift it also assigns [default property values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID206), like here

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController {
    private var _dataSource = SomeOtherClass()
}
```

Second phase is when initializers are being called. That is why by the time your breakpoint triggers, the default property value for `_dataSource` has already been assigned.

The difference between

```
private var _dataSource = SomeOtherClass()
```

and

```
private var _dataSource: SomeOtherClass!
```

is that in the second example you are only declaring a property, which needs to be initialized somewhere further along the road, whereas in the first one you declare it and provide it with a default value.

Note that in the first example, you don't need to explicitly specify the type of the property, because the compiler can infer it from the default value.